# GrapesJS asset manager not displaying assets

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

I'm using the latest version of GrapesJS at the time of this writing. I'm following the example on the website (https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Assets.html#initialization) but the pre-loaded assets are simply not displaying. I've tried every possible workaround I can think of. Even the most basic example does not work. Here is that code:

```
    var editor = grapesjs.init({
    container : '#gjs',
    components: '<div class="txt-red">Hello world!</div>',
    assetManager: {
        assets: [
            {
                type: 'image',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                name: 'display name',
                src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/50x50'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

I've tried using the API as well to manually add them AFTER GrapesJS editor is initialized (https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Assets.html#programmatic-usage). I'm able to then traverse through them via code and they are returned in the console, but they do not show up in the UI. Is anyone else having any issues or any suggestions? I'm using GrapesJS version 0.20.4.